# How to display Parsley error messages before inputs instead of after?

Tags: javascript, validation, parsley.js

Parsley.js appends error messages to the end of the specified error container element. But I want error messages to appear before inputs, rather than after:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <ul>
        <li>This value is required.</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label><input type="radio" name="myButton" value="yes" required="required">Yes</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="myButton" value="no" required="required">No</label>
    </div>
    <!-- This is where the error message would go by default. -->
</div>
```

Is this possible? I can't find mention of anything similar in the docs.

(I'm changing the error container class along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642409/erroneous-placement-of-error-message-span-with-parsley-2-x-and-bootstrap-3).)

Comment: Did you manage to work this out at all?

Comment: No, sorry. As far as I can tell it's impossible, which is a shame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old question, but for people who come across this question as I did there is a solution. Parsley allows you to define custom containers for error messages.

A simple example:

```
<form class="quoteForm" data-parsley-validate>
   <div class="nameError"></div>
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-errors-container=".nameError"/>
</form>
```

The key is the:

```
data-parsley-errors-container=".nameError"
```

Which specifies a custom box to hold the error message. Since this is above the form input you'll end up with  the error nicely above it.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this Peter! I don't know how I missed that - and it looks like it was in the version I would have been using in 2014. I scoured the docs but somehow missed it. I haven't had a chance to try this out, but as it's in the docs I'll mark it as the answer!